# Installing SPSS 25 with Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, 17.10

I am trying to install SPSS 25 (I know PSPP would be another good option for quick and dirty stats, but it's an ongoing project...) on Ubuntu 17.10 and keep getting an

```
Installer User Interface Mode Not Supported
```

error.
I installed the following packages:

```
- libgtk2.0-0:i386
- libpangox-1.0-0:i386
- libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386
- libidn11:i386
```

and then also tried if ia32-libs (now apparently replaced by lib32ncurses5 and  lib32z1) makes a difference, but it's still not working. Any ideas on whether it is actually a 32/64 issue or I'm missing something else?

Comment: I have a question. What version did you start with? Did you use Windows with wine, alter Mac, or did you get a Linux version. If the last, was it from IBM or a third party seller?

Comment: Please write the answer in the space marked **Your Answer**. Then after waiting for the required time, you will be able to mark your answer as the accepted correct answer. This will help others.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense - have done that now.
Wrt your other question:  It was a Linux version acquired through a third party seller (university).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else running into this problem I finally figured out that the `libgfortran3` package is another requirement (see the list of requirements for Ubuntu 16.04 here: https://ibm.co/2ptyTQy). Installing that fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, that's the one - apologies for the lack of clarity.